# Can we set an array in WSO2ESB?

Tags: xpath, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I wish to set an array in WSO2ESB in my scenario.

I am sending two parameters to database and getting number of rows but I need only one row.

My configuration is

```
<target>
               <sequence>
                  <property name="partybranchid"
                            expression="get-property('partybranchid')"
                            scope="default"
                            type="STRING"/>
                  <payloadFactory>
                     <format>
                        <p:Select_MailDetails_Op xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                           <xs:assetid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$1</xs:assetid>
                           <xs:partybranchid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$2</xs:partybranchid>
                        </p:Select_MailDetails_Op>
                     </format>
                     <args>
                        <arg expression="get-property('assetid')"/>
                        <arg expression="get-property('partybranchid')"/>
                     </args>
                  </payloadFactory>
<log level="full"/>
                  <send receive="Mail_Seq">
                     <endpoint>
                        <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/massetparametersetdetail_DataService/"
                                 format="soap11"/>
                     </endpoint>
                  </send>
               </sequence>
            </target>
```

and I am receiving data in this sequence:

```
<log><property xmlns:v="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="primarymail" action="set"
             expression="//v:primarymail/text()"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/></log>
 <iterate xmlns:v="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
            xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
            id="Mail"
            expression="//v:Datalist">
      <target>
         <sequence>
            <property xmlns:v="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="primarymail"
             expression="//v:primarymail/text()"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
           <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="assetname"
             expression="//assetname/text()"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="assetcode"
             expression="//assetcode/text()"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="activityname"
             expression="//activityname/text()"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="username"
             expression="//username/text()"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="parametername"
             expression="//parametername/text()"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="uomcode"
             expression="//uomcode/text()"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="tododetails"
             expression="fn:concat('AssetName:',get-property('assetname'),',','AssetCode:',get-property('assetcode'),',','ActivityName:',get-property('activityname'),',','UserName:',get-property('username'),',','ParameterName:',get-property('parametername'),',','UomCode:',get-property('uomcode'))"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
 <log><property xmlns:v="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="primarymail" action="set"
             expression="//v:primarymail/text()"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/></log>
             </sequence>
      </target>
   </iterate>
   </sequence>
```

and I am getting response like below but I want to send a mail only once.

Here  my mailid is repeating. How can I take out this mail id?

> response, primarymail =
>   mail@myunisoft.commail@myunisoft.commail@myunisoft.commail@myunisoft.commail@myunisoft.commail@myunisoft.commail@myunisoft.commail@myunisoft.commail@myunisoft.commail@myunisoft.com

How can I take single mail for this?

Comment: In the sequence which you are receiving data, you can put a <log level="full"> before everything else and see how the response from the  "assetparametersetdetail_DataService" looks like. It can be you are iterating over the wrong element. If you post the response message here (after removing the sensitive data of course), we might be able to help with the correct xpath too.

Comment: thanx for replay..its iterating as per row in database but i need it as array values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your webservice response is a SOAP message and What you get in to any mediator in ESB, is that particular incoming message. You cannot directly have an array of values. 
- One option is to use a class mediator and extract your desired value/s and set that value to a property in message context and use it.
- if the response payload can be altered in your scenario, return the response with a known delimiter and use xpath String operations to get your value.